# WooCommerce: Wrong Order Status Updated

Tags: woocommerce

I've created a brand new WP plugin and I try to update order status with this code (I use WC 6.6.0) :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_register_post_type', 'aapi_process' );
function aapi_process() {
  $order = wc_get_order( 'order_id' );
  $order->update_status( 'completed' );
  $order->add_order_note( 'My User Note', 1 );
}
```

But now my order disappears of orders admin list.

On DB, order post has `completed` to `post_status`, instead of `wc-completed`

When I change to `wc-completed`, order appears now.

`update_status` method on `WC_Order` class use `set_status` method on `Abstract_WC_Order`.
This method convert status without `wc-` : `$new_status = 'wc-' === substr( $new_status, 0, 3 ) ? substr( $new_status, 3 ) : $new_status;` (line 553) and put to prop with `$this->set_prop( 'status', $new_status );`

Order Note work fine.

Do you have an idea ? May be wrong hook ?

**------------ EDIT ------------**

Work fine with `init` hook

```
add_action( 'init', 'aapi_process' );
function aapi_process() {
  $order = wc_get_order( 'order_id' );
  $order->update_status( 'completed' );
  $order->add_order_note( 'My User Note', 1 );
}
```

Comment: This question is not similar to [Woocommerce: Programmatically Updating Order Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847681/woocommerce-programmatically-updating-order-status). Status order on DB is not done properly

Comment: You are using: `$order = wc_get_order( 'order_id' );`, however the **order_id** is not set or determined/defined.. - In brief. You don't specify which `$order` object to update

Comment: `'order_id'` is an exemple. I give a good order id and `$order` is an instance of `WC_Order`. Order note works fine.
 `var_dump( $order instanceof WC_Order )` return `true`

Comment: Works with `init` hook